# player does not collide with walls unity 5

Tags: unity, unityscript

I just started a new proyect with a personalize first person controller, like arrow move style, it worked, but when I tryed to collide it with walls it did not happen, I tryed adding a capsule, then adding the camera, rigidbody, character controller and my script to that capsule , then if you can see there are two walls one with box collider trigger the other one unchecked, it walks around but it does not collide at all, i'll add my controller script + scereenshot, thanks for you time

```
#pragma strict

public var speed = 100.5;

function Update () {
//rotate
var horizontalDir = parseFloat(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Rotate(0, horizontalDir, 0);

//move backward and foreward
var verticalDir = parseFloat(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * (speed / 10) * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Translate(0,0, verticalDir);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we update the script as follows

```
#pragma strict

var walkSpeed = 150;
var rotateSpeed = 100;
var jumpSpeed : float = 8.0;
var gravity : float = 20.0;

private var moveDirection : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

function Update () {
var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent.<CharacterController>();

if (controller.isGrounded) {
    // We are grounded, so recalculate
    // move direction directly from axes
    moveDirection = Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    moveDirection *= walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    //also with jump ;)
    if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
        moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }
}

// Apply gravity 
moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

// Move the controller
controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

// rotate controller
var horizontalDir = parseFloat(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Rotate(0, horizontalDir, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Translating the Transform component directly doesn't not apply collision detection. You'll want to use Move() on the CharacterController.